# Total up values of table cell but only one value is allowed per row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a scorecard program which allows the user to select cells of a table and gauge a score, I'm at a point where I can add each score the user clicks (admittedly in probably a very clunky way) but my problem is that the way the logic works is that only one value per row can be chosen. Here's an example - http://jsfiddle.net/5q9nS/2/

To clarify, if the user chooses "#a1" the value of "2" should be added to the total. If the user then selects "#b1" this value should subtract the previously selected value because duplicate values from the same row are not allowed. However the total should add any value choosen from the rows a2-c2, a3-e3, a4-c4 etc.....

I hope that's clear, the logic for the selected classes works to try and further demonstrate.

Any help would be hugely appreciated! As you will be able to tell i'm just on the learning curve and need to hit the summit.

HTML

```
<table width="100%" id="pcpScoring">
  <tr>
    <td width="30%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="14%" class="tblLabel">Own Savings</td>
    <td width="14%" class="tblLabel">Bank or B.S. Loan</td>
    <td width="14%" class="tblLabel">Dealer Finance</td>
    <td width="14%" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="14%" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td>How do you normally fund your vehicle?</td>
    <td class="tblNumber"><a id="a1">2</a></td>
    <td class="tblNumber"><a id="b1">4</a></td>
    <td class="tblNumber"><a id="c1">3</a></td>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tblLabel">1-2 years</td>
    <td class="tblLabel">3 years</td>
    <td class="tblLabel">4 years</td>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td>How often would you &quot;ideally&quot; like to change your vehicle?</td>
    <td class="tblNumber"><a id="a2">4</a></td>
    <td class="tblNumber"><a id="b2">2</a></td>
    <td class="tblNumber"><a id="c2">1</a></td>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tblLabel">upto 6,000</td>
    <td class="tblLabel">6-12,000</td>
    <td class="tblLabel">12-18,000</td>
    <td class="tblLabel">18-25,000</td>
    <td class="tblLabel">over 25,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td>How many miles do you drive per year?</td>
    <td class="tblNumber"><a id="a3">5</a></td>
    <td class="tblNumber"><a id="b3">4</a></td>
    <td class="tblNumber"><a id="c3">3</a></td>
    <td class="tblNumber"><a id="d3">2</a></td>
    <td class="tblNumber"><a id="e3">1</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tblLabel">Part Exchange</td>
    <td class="tblLabel">Private Sale</td>
    <td class="tblLabel">Pass on to Famiy</td>
    <td class="tblLabel">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tblLabel">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td>How do you usually dispose of your vehicle? </td>
    <td class="tblNumber"><a id="a4">4</a></td>
    <td class="tblNumber"><a id="b4">2</a></td>
    <td class="tblNumber"><a id="c4">1</a></td>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6" class="tblNumber" style="text-align:right"><span class="total">Total Score</span><span id="pcpScore" class="total">0</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//PCP Scorecard  on Click add class 
$('.tblNumber a').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');                             

});

$('#a1').click(function() {                 
$(this).addClass('selected');
  $('#b1, #c1').removeClass('selected');

addUp(parseInt($(this).text()));

});

$('#b1').click(function() {                 
$(this).addClass('selected');
  $('#a1, #c1').removeClass('selected');
    addUp(parseInt($(this).text()));
});

$('#c1').click(function() {                 
$(this).addClass('selected');
  $('#a1, #b1').removeClass('selected');
  addUp(parseInt($(this).text()));  
});

$('#a2').click(function() {                 
$(this).addClass('selected');
  $('#b2, #c2').removeClass('selected');
    addUp(parseInt($(this).text()));
});

$('#b2').click(function() {                 
$(this).addClass('selected');
  $('#a2, #c2').removeClass('selected');
    addUp(parseInt($(this).text()));
});

$('#c2').click(function() {                 
$(this).addClass('selected');
  $('#a2, #b2').removeClass('selected');
    addUp(parseInt($(this).text()));
});


$('#a3').click(function() {                 
$(this).addClass('selected');
  $('#b3, #c3, #d3,  #e3').removeClass('selected');
    addUp(parseInt($(this).text()));
});

$('#b3').click(function() {                 
$(this).addClass('selected');
  $('#a3, #c3, #d3,  #e3').removeClass('selected');
    addUp(parseInt($(this).text()));
});

$('#c3').click(function() {                 
$(this).addClass('selected');
  $('#a3, #b3, #d3,  #e3').removeClass('selected');
    addUp(parseInt($(this).text()));
});
$('#d3').click(function() {                 
$(this).addClass('selected');
  $('#a3, #c3, #e3,  #b3').removeClass('selected');
addUp(parseInt($(this).text()));
});

$('#e3').click(function() {                 
$(this).addClass('selected');
  $('#a3, #b3, #c3,  #d3').removeClass('selected');
addUp(parseInt($(this).text()));
});



$('#a4').click(function() {                 
$(this).addClass('selected');
  $('#b4, #c4').removeClass('selected');
addUp(parseInt($(this).text()));
});

$('#b4').click(function() {                 
$(this).addClass('selected');
  $('#a4, #c4').removeClass('selected');
addUp(parseInt($(this).text()));
});

$('#c4').click(function() {                 
$(this).addClass('selected');
  $('#a4, #b4').removeClass('selected');
addUp(parseInt($(this).text()));

});


    function addUp(addScore) {      


var totalScore  = (parseInt($('#pcpScore').text())) + addScore;    
            $('#pcpScore').html(totalScore);  

}


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish all you need within the click function:

```
$('.tblNumber a').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').find('a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var total = 0;
    $('.tblNumber .selected').each(function() { 
        total += parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    $('#pcpScore').text(total);
});
```

Line by line it: Clears the previously selected items in the row, selects the current item, then iterates over the selected items in the table adding to the total then sets the text in the pcpScore span.

**EDIT:** Working jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/cbailster/ycymB/

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I sensed that I was making the task more complicated that it needed to be but I wasn't aware the solution could be so elegant. Thanks again, very much appreciated!!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. As a general rule, I like to think there are very few instances where you need separate code to handle events on individual DOM elements, 99 times out of 100 there's a way to role the code up into a single function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "each" method in jquery to traverse each of your rows.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

```
$('table tr').each(function() { /*Magic Happens Here*/ });
```

Then, you can target a specific cell by using the "eq()" selector
http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

```
$('table tr').each(function() { 
     var value = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text(); //second cell in the row 
});
```

You can even just use a single selector

```
$('table tr td:eq(1)').each(function() { 
     var value = $(this).text(); //second cell in the row 
});
```

Use selectors, you get the idea ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/5q9nS/2/

And the JS:

```
var totalDiv = $('#pcpScore');

$('.tblNumber').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.hasClass('selected')){
        var prevSelected = $this.siblings('.selected');
        $this.addClass('selected');
        prevSelected.removeClass('selected');

        var currentTotal = +totalDiv.text(); //the plus sign converts this to a number
        var prevSelectedVal = +prevSelected.children('a').text();
        var newSelectedVal = +$this.children('a').text();
        totalDiv.text(currentTotal + newSelectedVal - prevSelectedVal);
    }
});
```

First we store the element that holds the total in a variable because we're going to need to access it every time a `.tblNumber` is clicked. This makes the script more efficient because it doesn't have to re-find that element every time.

After that, we simply bind a click event handler to every `.tblNumber` element. We then use jQuery's DOM traversal methods to deselect the previously selected `.tblNumber` in that row, as well as get it's value and the new value so that we can adjust the total appropriately.

Having looked at your original code, the key to dramatically shortening it like I did here is the `this` keyword. While `this` can be a complicated topic in JS, when used inside an event handler (`.click(function(){...})`) like this, it refers to the element the fired the event. So it gives us the context of the event, which is what allows us to identify the correct cells, rather than binding a slightly different click event handler to every single cell, as you had done.